# C# background worker execute s.play() once only

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a background worker that executes evry time when data recived on serial port, and inside is some code, i would like to play some music file, just the first time that background worker executes, can somebody please help me ?
code:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
.....

s.play();

...
}
```

Comment: what object type is `s`? Does it have an `IsPlaying` property or something like this? Otherwise why don't you simply persist whether `s.play()` has been called previously into a `bool` field and check this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably just use a boolean class level field and set it after first call to DoWork, and then check in each call to see if you need to initiate play.